# How likely/possible is it that the NSA have broken common encryption techniques such as SSL/TLS?

Tags: encryption, tls

Jumping on the NSA/Prism questions bandwagon - There's been a lot more attention drawn to facilities such as [Room 641A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Room_641A) which indicate that the NSA has been, amongst other things, applying mass intercepts to communications through large US ISPs.

One thing that strikes me as odd in these techniques is that although they could collect a large amount of unencrypted data, large sites such as Google, Facebook, Twitter and many others typically redirect to HTTPS sites by default. This begs the question - how useful can the unencrypted data be, and do intelligence agencies have a way to decrypt the rest of it?

I know as little about this program as the next guy, but a lot of the descriptions of this program indicate that various intelligence agencies use demands such as [National Security Letters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_security_letter) to request information, or make demands such as that on [Verizon](http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/interactive/2013/jun/06/verizon-telephone-data-court-order) to have metadata sent back on a recurring basis. If that's the case, what purpose could monitoring/recording internet traffic serve?

It's my understanding that, without having broken SSL/TLS the only way to decrypt encrypted traffic would be through having access to either a root certificate, forging a certificate for the domain you want to monitor and running a MITM attack, or through having access to the private key of the domain you want to monitor.

On the other hand, the NSA are much further ahead in crypto research than any public body, so there could be a possibility they've found a weakness? (Or simply have the compute power to break it through brute force)

Edit 2013-09-06: The Guardian has today published a story that something alarmingly similar to my question is taking place. [Article here](http://www.theguardian.com/world/2013/sep/05/nsa-gchq-encryption-codes-security)

Comment: not sure why the downvotes

Comment: It seems a bit speculative and hard to answer definitively. I didn't  downvote it because I'm curious.

Comment: Why intercept and decrypt data from people who hand it out in clear text on a whim?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There isn't really a reliable way to know for sure.  What we do know from public knowledge is that algorithms exist that allow for fairly efficient breaking of relative prime based algorithms.  We also know that there are now functioning quantum computers though none with sufficient quality or processing power to run the algorithms.

What we can't know is if more powerful quantum computers exist that could crack them.  Either way, even if such computers do exist, it would be expensive and they would only be able to crack a limited number of cases, so your chances of having your information picked up if protected are most likely minor.

It's also worth noting this is only applicable if you are using your own keys.  If you are talking with a US based company, they could simply go to that company to get the information, no cracking of the encryption keys would be necessary.

If you are using your own key and not doing anything nefarious, it is most likely that the NSA wouldn't use the resources necessary to crack your encryption due to its expense.  This of course rules out any very well hidden back doors that "might" exist, but seeing as no cryptographers have publicized such a problem, it is unlikely (though I suppose not impossible) that such a hole exists.

Update: While links are generally discouraged, since someone asked for them specifically.  The [DWave Two](http://www.dwavesys.com/en/dw_homepage.html) is a commercially available (though unable to run Shor's algorithm and may not be truly quantum), functioning quantum computer, though not at sufficient qbits or noise levels to be an issue yet. (But who knows what might be not publicly available based on the state of the art.)  [Shor's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm) is a well known quantum algorithm for factoring large primes.  This greatly decreases the effectiveness of any relative prime derived asymmetric cryptography algorithm (which most common ones are based on.)  Also [Grover's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm) should greatly reduce the complexity of cracking symmetric cryptographic algorithms, though a simple increase in bit length will compensate.

Comment: could you please add some links/citations to "know" (quantum computers, efficient breaking, etc.)

Comment: @naxa - updated answer with relevant links.

Comment: The number of qubits is the smallest issue with DWave's computer. It is not able to run general purpose quantum algorithms, in particular it can't run Shor's algo. From what I heard it's not even entirely clear if it's actually a quantum computer at all.

Comment: Agree with @CodesInChaos.  DWave can only do quantum annealing algorithms (not Shor or Grover) and only for one very specific type of problem (the DWave Problem) and its qubits are very noisy with a high-error rate (ok for Monte Carlo simulations).  The evidence seems to be that it does have quantum effects, but there's no suggestion whatsoever that its in any faster than [optimized classical annealing algorithms](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=1400).  Quantum computing is very interesting work (Umesh Varizani has a good MOOC at edx.org on quantum computing).

Comment: thank you very much for the links! off-note (meta): afaik, links are "discouraged" only when no other information is given in an answer/quetsion, but when the information is provided on-site, as citation sources they are encouraged. or at least this is how I thought and what makes sense to me. either way, thank you very much!

Comment: @CodesInChaos - good to know, I hadn't followed the development closely enough since I just evaluated that that one on it's own couldn't do it and didn't particular care beyond there.  It does raise what if questions though since historically, the NSA has had more advanced computers than conventionally available before.  If things like DWave are making it in to the commercial world, it raises the chances that NSA may have something more advanced.  I updated my answer to reflect the doubts about the DWave.

Comment: @drjimbob - thanks for the additional info on the limitations of the DWave.  Made for a very informative read.  I mostly was just pointing to it as an example of an existing system (which shows progress is being made and generally military tends to lead development.)  My main point in bringing it up is simply that if such a thing exists and works, it is possible that highly funded classified work where "cost isn't an issue" may have produced more advanced work.  It doesn't guarantee such a thing exists, but it does make it much less unbelievable that it might.

Comment: @AJ - Agree, it is relevant to bring up, who knows when large-scale QC will be feasible.  It still seems a far way off, though it would not surprise me if the NSA etc has a headstart (though rumors would likely leak out).  I try and double the lengths of my symmetric keys to be secure against quantum algorithms (e.g., 256-bit from 128-bit) as its easy (Grover's algorithm speeds up brute force attacks from O(N) to O(sqrt(N))).

Comment: Asymmetric is the bigger problem, as Shor's algorithm would break PKE schemes based on integer factorization/discrete logs (like RSA and El Gamal even with elliptic curves) in O(b^3) instead of sub-exponential.  So QC capable of factoring say 1024-bit numbers means a scale-up of only ~4 in number of qubits and ~64 in time would break 4096-bit RSA. (The classical scale-up is 10^11 from 1024 to 4096 bit RSA).  Granted, there are proposed [PKE schemes](http://middleware.internet2.edu/idtrust/2009/papers/07-perlner-quantum.pdf) that are resistant to Shor's algorithm (none in wide use though).

Comment: @drjimbob "D-Wave’s current processor architecture ... [is] not quantumly universal, although it’s really easy to make it so (just add a new coupling device) if some day it turns out there’s a good reason to do this."  [D-Wave's CTO](http://dwave.wordpress.com/2013/03/20/computational-universality/)  He also claims to [have algorithms better than Shor's](https://dwave.wordpress.com/2011/05/11/learning-to-program-the-d-wave-one/#comment-22008)....

Comment: @Indolering - First, the "Better than Shor" series of blog posts purported by the CTO was never published (nothing about Shor or factoring in the 2+ years since that comment), nor anything else about factoring integers.  If its "easy" to make a universal QC from their machines -- why hasn't it been made?  This would be a huge deal, would get their computers selling like hotcakes and easily demonstrate their power, no one would remain skeptical about their quantum nature and they could shatter the quantum factoring record (of 21 into 3x7).

Comment: @drjimbob I think we ALL wish D-Wave wouldn't be so coy about their technology.  I was just putting that out there : )

Answer (score 3):

If it is true that the government has access to the servers that are the target of the communication (e.g. Google/Facebook) there is no need to tamper with SSL/TLS because at the servers the traffic is unencrypted.

Comment: That's what I thought; why bother with a massive (and expensive as hell!) wiretap when you have 95% of the info you want available under PATRIOT act/NSL style access?

Answer (score 1):

I think this paper is related with the subject and it is an interesting paper :) ...

N.J. AlFardan and K.G. Paterson, **Plaintext-Recovery Attacks Against Datagram TLS**. In Network and Distributed System Security Symposium (NDSS 2012). Distinguished Paper Award.

http://www.isg.rhul.ac.uk/~kp/dtls.pdf

Answer (score 1):

One technique that has always been suspected is to deliberately weaken otherwise strong encryption by various means.   No smoking guns have been disclosed as far as I know, but
conspiracy theorists can always speculate that any flaw, once discovered, was put there deliberately.

The famous example was that the NSA influenced IBM to alter the S-Boxes for DES.  It was suspected that this was for their own, not our, benefit.  I think this has been completely
debunked now - that the change was actually to make the code stronger; but the elephant in the room is that DES used only 56 bit keys.

Another, recent example, was that a survey discovered that an alarmingly small number of
secret primes were actually in use RSA public keys.  Apparently the means of selecting random primes in several popular RSA implementations wasn't random enough.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the NSA have invested a large amount of resources into brute-forcing the primes. This would be thankless work were it not for the particular (lazy) implementation of Diffie-Hellman, which regurgitates from a small selection of 1024-bit primes.

Spending a few 100m, an adversary can make a machine that cracks 1 such prime a year. So what's the payoff? Breaking a single, common 1024-bit prime would allow NSA to passively decrypt connections to two-thirds of VPNs and a quarter of all SSH servers globally. Breaking a second 1024-bit prime would allow passive eavesdropping on connections to nearly 20% of the top million HTTPS websites. In other words, a one-time investment in massive computation would make it possible to eavesdrop on trillions of encrypted connections.

(Why the weak implementation? Finding a large strong prime, of the right sort is difficult. it's not hard to find suitable *candidates* (there are plenty of algorithms to do that on your laptop) but another thing to check they're prime. Secondly, sender & receiver need to agree. )
https://freedom-to-tinker.com/2015/10/14/how-is-nsa-breaking-so-much-crypto/